# How to fix the following error building a neuronal network?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

Hello I am updating the following function:

```
def train(self, features, targets):
```

the idea is to make the todo of my online course I tried this:

```
# TODO: Output error - Replace this value with your calculations.
            error = y - final_outputs # Output layer error is the difference between desired target and actual output.

            # TODO: Backpropagated error terms - Replace these values with your calculations.
            output_error_term = error * final_outputs * (1 - final_outputs)

            # TODO: Calculate the hidden layer's contribution to the error
            hidden_error = np.dot(output_error_term, self.weights_hidden_to_output)

            # TODO: Backpropagated error terms - Replace these values with your calculations.      
            hidden_error_term = hidden_error * hidden_outputs * (1 - hidden_outputs)
```

however I got:

```
..FFE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_train (__main__.TestMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-90579d706c92>", line 41, in test_train
    network.train(inputs, targets)
  File "<ipython-input-9-596e703ab9b6>", line 65, in train
    hidden_error = np.dot(output_error_term, self.weights_hidden_to_output)
ValueError: shapes (1,) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)

======================================================================
FAIL: test_data_path (__main__.TestMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-90579d706c92>", line 20, in test_data_path
    self.assertTrue(data_path.lower() == 'bike-sharing-dataset/hour.csv')
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: test_run (__main__.TestMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-90579d706c92>", line 56, in test_run
    self.assertTrue(np.allclose(network.run(inputs), 0.09998924))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=1)
```

this is the complete code, I downloaded my notebook of ipython to show my complete code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e7a816ef0526d41fbdb63a0aa6c27712

I really appreciate support to overcome this issue thanks a lot for the support.

this is the data:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/31340c38a3fd8e175bf0054c7c005d2b

thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
hidden_error = np.dot(output_error_term, self.weights_hidden_to_output)
```

Remember dot product requires that the number of columns of the first operand ,matches the number of rows of the second operand.  You have
 (1,1) X (2,1) 
So the number of rows of the second operand should be 1 ,that means you need:

(1,1)X(1,2)

That means you need to transpose the second operand, try:

```
hidden_error = np.dot(output_error_term, self.weights_hidden_to_output.T)
```

But i think after fixing this error, you will find  similar errors because of shape inconsistencies. Manipulate your operands to match the columns on  the first, with the rows in the second.